# Showing that the Ricci scalar equals a product of commutators

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, general-relativity

I have to compute the square of the Dirac operator, $D=\gamma^a e^\mu_a D_\mu$ , in curved space time ($D_\mu\Psi=\partial_\mu \Psi + A_\mu ^{ab}\Sigma_{ab}$ is the covariant derivative of the spinor field and $\Sigma_{ab}$ the Lorentz generators involving gamma matrices). Dirac equation for the massless fermion is $\gamma^a e^\mu_a D_\mu \Psi=0$. In particular I have to show that Dirac spinors obey the following equation: $$(-D_\mu D^\mu + \frac{1}{4}R)\Psi=0 \qquad (1)$$ where R is (I guess) the Ricci scalar.
Appling to the Dirac eq, the operator $\gamma^\nu D_\nu$ and decomposing the product $\gamma^\mu \gamma^\nu$ in symmetric and antisymmetric part I found: $$D_\mu D^\mu\Psi + \frac{1}{4}[\gamma^\mu,\gamma^\nu][D_\mu, D_\nu]\Psi=0$$Now I have troubles to show that this last object is related with the Ricci scalar. Can somebody help me or suggest me the right way to solve Eq. $(1)$?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of $\frac{1}{4}[\gamma^\mu,\gamma^\nu]$, you should have obtained $\frac{1}{2}\gamma^\mu\gamma^\nu$. The commutator of the derivatives gives rise to the curvature 2-form. Use one of the gamma matrices to reduce the curvature 2-form down to the Ricci tensor. Then, recover the Ricci scalar using the anti-commutation relations of the gamma matrices and the symmetric nature of the Ricci tensor.