# Looking for a reference for $\gamma_a e^{a}_{\mu} D^\mu \gamma_b e^{b}_{\nu} D^\nu =D^\mu D_\mu - \tfrac{1}{4}R$

Tags: general-relativity, resource-recommendations, quantum-electrodynamics, quantum-chromodynamics, dirac-equation

I am having trouble finding references for the following identities:

Dirac Operator:
$$
\gamma_a e^{a}_{\mu} D^\mu \gamma_b e^{b}_{\nu} D^\nu =D^\mu D_\mu - \tfrac{1}{4}R
\tag{1}
$$

QED Operator:
$$
\gamma_a e^{a}_{\mu} (D^\mu -iA^\mu ) \gamma_b e^{b}_{\nu} (D^\nu-iA^\mu) = \\(D^\mu -iA^\mu )(D_\mu -iA_\mu ) - \tfrac{1}{4}R -2 \sigma^{\mu\nu} F_{\mu\nu}
\tag{2}
$$

QCD Operator:
$$
\gamma_a e^{a}_{\mu} (D^\mu -i t_nA_n^\mu ) \gamma_b e^{b}_{\nu} (D^\nu-i t^mA_m^\mu) =\\ (D^\mu -i t^nA_n^\mu )(D_\mu -it_mA^m_\mu ) - \tfrac{1}{4}R -2 \sigma^{\mu\nu} t_nF_{\mu\nu}^n
\tag{3}
$$

where $\gamma$ are the Dirac matrices, $e$ is the vielbein, $D$ is the covariant derviative, $R$ is the ricci scalar, $A$ is the electromagnetic four potential, $F$ is the electromagnetic field tensor, $\sigma$ are the Dirac bi-linear matrices, $A^a$ are the eight gluon four potentials, $F^a$ are the eight gluon field tensors, and $t^a$ are the Gell-Mann matrices.

Answer (score 0):

For the first equation,

$ D_{\mu}D^{\mu} -\frac{1}{4}R $

This has been detailed at...

[Dirac Equation in General Relativity](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/51368/dirac-equation-in-general-relativity)

Hope that's what you're looking for.